# Magento new font for admin theme

Tags: magento-1.9, php, css, font-family

i like to add a new font to magento admin theme, for that i put the font file in "FederalLawyer/skin/adminhtml/default/lawyeradmintheme/fonts"

```
in my css file i called :
------------------------
 @font-face{
        font-family:'FontAwesome';
        src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
        src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0')
        format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0')
        format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0')
        format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular')
        format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}

but still is not get call.
see the below screen you will know that.
```

[image]

Comment: What is the path to your css files?

Comment: FederalLawyer/skin/adminhtml/default/lawyeradmintheme/reset.css

Answer (score 1):

By default magento does NOT support custom admin theme, but you could enable this using

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <default>lawyeradmintheme</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719777/want-to-over-ride-adminhtml-in-magento

Comment: Also note that Magento looks for a `custom. css` in admin themes so you can create it and add your styles without further modification